# Virtualhost setup for Ruby on Rails application (mod passenger)

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm trying to install Redmine under apache. The apache server works on a local network.
My apache setup consist on a single virtual host. I can get insto different directories using simply the path corresponding:

http://ip_address/folder_of_the_project_1

How can I setup the virtualhost to make redmine works in this situation?
Here is my current virtualhost setup:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/redmine/public>                
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.        
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    ServerSignature On

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Thank you,
Ingo86

Answer (score 4):

Point DocumentRoot at your Redmine public directory, and RailsBaseURI to point at /.

Here's an example from my working Ubuntu server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName redmine.int.example.com
  ServerAlias redmine
  DocumentRoot /var/www/redmine/public

  RailsBaseURI /
  RailsEnv production

  PassengerMaxPoolSize 4

  <Directory /var/www/redmine/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

  LogLevel info
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/redmine-error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/redmine-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I have other directory here:
http://ip_addr/redmine
http://ip_addr/docs

With your suggestion how can I access my docs directory?

Comment: http://redmine.int.example.com/projects/myproject/documents accesses the documents directory of the 'myproject' project.

Comment: How can i access my other directories with your setup?
for example http :// lan_ip_add/ other_dir

Comment: Is 'other_dir' another web application? You'd need to set up virtualhosts for them, or specify them with <Directory> directives.

Comment: Yes, it's another application. How can i set up different virtualhost on a server inside a LAN? I can't use subdomains!

Comment: Hi, I have a wiki (php mediawiki base url /wiki ), and a django app (base url /) in the same virtual host, now we'd like to add redmine at /bugs - using passenger. Is it possible to set all of that up in the same virtualhost?

Comment: Evgeny you should probably ask that as a new question :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **`RailsBaseURI /redmine/public`** instead of **`RailsBaseURI /redmine`**? just in case.

Comment: Yes, it's not working. Internal server errror.

Comment: Could you tell what's the error report in your error.log?

Answer (score 0):

Someone suggested pointing the DocumentRoot to the root of redmine directory as this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName golem.it
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/redmine/public"

    <Directory /var/www/redmine/public>
            AllowOverride all
            Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

the above of course works however it does neither answer the specific question asked neither does it give a general solution which doesn't require stealing the documentroot completely from other applications.

The solution I found requires to create a symlink to /var/www/redmine-2.2/public named redmines (notice it is not redmine but redmines due to a possible Passenger naming bug!), the solution is shown below (ignore the ssl part):

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName golem.it
    DocumentRoot "/var/www"
    Options +Indexes
    Options +ExecCGI

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/redmine-2.2
    RailsBaseURI /redmines
    Alias /redmine /var/www/redmines
    <Directory /var/www/redmines>
            AllowOverride All
            Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/dwewe.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/wefew.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/wefer/ca.crt
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
</VirtualHost>
```